# Include external javascript file as a module in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm very beginner on Angularjs and I want to use my existing javascript code in Angularjs controller without modifiying my existing js code.
I have tried some ways but I couldn't make it work. I also don't know if it is usable in Angularjs with that way. Is there anybody faced with the similar problem? How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Please show at least the way your actual code is achieving. A piece of code could be helpful

Comment: Using browserify as package manager and using brwserfiy shim, you can do that.

Comment: thanks @ Indra I will look at it. @DeblatonJean-Philippe The code is very long,complex and I'm afraid I can't find and give you the exact example that suits my situation. I use that library https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erdkse/sipml5/master/SIPml.js and say in 'example.js' I have some variables and functions. I want to take that 'example.js' and use in my angularjs controller and reach its functions and variables. Is that possible? Is there a way to do it?